# Referencing a type through JSDoc comments in VS

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

In C#, you can reference a type using [`<see cref=... />`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837134), for example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds a <see cref="Note" /> to the collection.
/// </summary>
public void Add(Note note) ...
```

IntelliSense will then display the referenced class with a teal highlight (as it does for types), and consider this comment when refactoring (e.g. renaming `Note` to `Message`):

[image: IntelliSense with XMLDoc]

**How can I do the same for TypeScript? (which uses JSDoc-style comments)**

---

Now, according to the JSDoc docs, the [`{@link ...}`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-inline-link.html) inline tag should be used for this task, but the supposed functionality is not recognized by VS:

```
/**
 * Adds a {@link Note} to the collection.
 */
public add(note: Note): void ...
```

[image: IntelliSense with JSDoc]

---

**Edit:** I just stumbled upon [Support JSDoc @link in TypeScript](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/12796299-support-jsdoc-link-in-typescript), so `@link` is clearly not supported at this time. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: have you thought about using tsdoc instead of jsdoc? https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsdoc

Comment: @toskv I'm not sure how this would integrate with IntelliSense.

Comment: indeed, I was looking for a vscode extension but there doesn't seem to be one.. I guess navigating via the type directly will have to do for now..